# Django - using intermediate user group model

Tags: django, django-models

I need to use the intermediate model between user and group in another model like this:

```
Class SomeModel(models.Model):
    usergroup = models.ForeignKey(UserGroupIntermediate, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHINH)
```

That is possible?
Thanks!

EDIT!:
 My model looks like this, i'm using a custom user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel


class Enrollment(TimeStampedModel):

    usergroups = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model().groups.through,
```

but, this return an error when execute makemigrations

```
enrollments.Enrollment.usergroups: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'User_groups', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the model via the `through` attribute of the field.

```
usergroup = models.ForeignKey(User.groups.through, ...)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Daniel. is not working:

enrollments.Enrollment.usergroups: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'User_groups', which is either not installed, or is abstract.